# Check if an array contains all the values greater than another array at the same index

Tags: c#, arrays

For any two given arrays, is there any simple way of checking if all the elements of one array are greater than that of the other array at the same index

For eg:

```
Arr1 = [1,2,3] and Arr2 = [2,3,4] returns true

while

Arr1 = [1,2,3] and Arr2 = [2,1,4] returns false
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing? As long as length of the arrays remains, this looks like a simple code to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ: `Zip` links via index and `All` evaluates a predicate and returns `false` on the first non-matching.

```
bool allGreater = Arr1.Zip(Arr2, (i1, i2) => i2 > i1).All(secondGreater => secondGreater);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Arr2.Length).All(i => Arr1[i] < Arr2[i])
```

Or, if the arrays can be different lengths:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(Arr1.Length, Arr2.Length))
    .All(i => Arr1[i] < Arr2[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop

```
function is2ArrayGreater(Arr1, Arr2){
  if(Arr1.length == Arr2.length){
    var isEqual = true;
    for(var i = 0; i< Arr1.length; i++){
      if(Arr1[i] >= Arr2[i]){
        isEqual = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    alert('result is: ' + isEqual);
  }
};
```